# Reference properties file outside src directory

Tags: java, properties

If I have the following directory structure,

+src
++com.foo.util
+++FooProperties.java
+foo.properties

How do I reference `foo.properties` as a resource stream in `FooProperties`? I've tried adding it to the classpath and referencing it as such,

```
FooProperties.class.getResourceAsStream("/foo.properties")
```

but I get a `NullPointerException`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put it inside `/src`. If you don't, I think you have to hardcode.

Comment: `/foo.properties` means the file is at the root of the classpath. If it's not in the calsspath, you need to provide absolute path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the `properties` file outside the `src`(same level as `src`), then you can fetch your `properties` file this way:-

```
try {
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
            "test.properties"));
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(fileStream);
    String myPropValue = (String) props.get("test.prop");
    System.out.println(myPropValue);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Hope it helps. You can even edit the properties file using the above method(no absolute path required).